# Wallet transfer upon death - what process is the safest for transferring wallet details to family members after death?

Tags: trust

What is a safe / vetted process for handing over wallet details to family members after death?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a safety deposit box containing the wallet keys with ownership of the box going to your spouse/family member on death. That way you can share the key with your spouse/family member before death  but they'll only have access to it as part of your will.

Comment: Thanks Edd, So will referencing safety deposit box and done? What happens if the bank (with the safety deposit box) "goes away"?

Comment: Banks are regulated so this shouldn't be a risk, but of course everything has some element of risk. I'd personally see this as an acceptable level of risk, however others might not. You can usually use a safety deposit box to pass important documents so this is a tried and tested method at least.

Comment: Thanks, didn't consider the regulation aspect.

Comment: Safety deposit box is a great suggestion, I would add a crypt-keeper  wallet into the mix for a good measure.